# Ambiguous output of SMTP and MailMessage class

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp

The recipient received the messages but not in the correct form. I am trying to send the messages through SMTP as below:

**WebConfig**:

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp>
    <network 
      host="smtp.gmail.com" 
      userName ="UserName" 
      password ="Password"
       port="587"/>

  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

**Default.aspx**:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        MailAddress from = new MailAddress("mahesh@uiti.5gbfree.com");
        MailAddress to = new MailAddress(DestiEmail.Text); //Gmail Email ID
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(from, to);
        msg.Subject = "New User Login Information";
        msg.Body = "User:- " + UserName.Text + " " + "New Loging";
        SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient();
        sc.EnableSsl = true;
        sc.Send(msg);
 }
```

The above code transfers the messages but not in correct form. I have checked the gmail inbox and found that gmail does not show from address, instead it shows “to” address as from address. E.g. my From address: `mahesh@uiti.5gbfree.com` and To address is :`mwaghela7@gmail.com` but it used `mwaghela7@gmail.com` as from address.

I have correctly bound the value of from and to address in `MailAddress` and provided the value of it in MailMessages as above but don't know why it is shows in wrong form?.

Is there a problem In MailMessages classes or in SMTP? What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: if this is possible I can send emails as `mwaghela7@gmail.com` :) I think SmtpClient with Gmail get `from` user as the authenticated user to make the smtp connection.

Comment: @Damith, If So then there is no use of MailAddress and MailMassages Class Isn't It?.

Comment: Idea is that some SMTPs (gmail in this particular case) can prevent you from changing FROM address, while others will easily allow it.

Comment: @Lanorkin, Your mean is some host not SMTP wright?.

Comment: @MaheshWagh no I mean SMTP - the server which you are use to send mail through. Usually SMTP knows your login/password, so it **really** know who you are, and thus may prevent you from frauding FROM field